# How to make hotkeys in VB6?

Tags: vb6, hotkeys

I've some problem, i'm planning to make a form can hide itself and the form can show again (activate it only with a hotkey). what's the source code for my problem?

Comment: Use the `RegisterHotKey` API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare with this

```
Dim i As Integer
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As     Integer
```

then make a timer

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyControl) And GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyR) Then
Frmsav.Show
End If
End Sub
```

that code using Ctrl + R to show your form