# How do I bind a hotkey to left click in VB6 and make it work in desktop and games?

Tags: vb6, click, bind

hi i want make make a hotkey in vb6 and work in desktop and games not only in app.
when i press 0 from my NuumLock I want press 3 and click left and also repeat it for 4 5 6 7 8 9 and 0

i found some codes in chat GPT but not work in desktop or idk if even work as well in app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make hotkeys in VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39939900/how-to-make-hotkeys-in-vb6)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GetAsyncKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) to do this.

Add this line to a Module in your project:

```
Public Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
```

Then, you can write a loop that checks for the keys you want.